# Contains em PHP in return Regex

Tags: php, preg-replace, strpos

I am having difficulty in searching for a specific word in text.

I tried to use the `stripos` method, but it throws an error because the text return is an object:

```
$text = preg_replace("/note:/" ,'' , $text);

if(stripos($text, "note:") !== false){
   return true
}
```

I need it to return if the string contains that word inside of the text to use in my `if`.

Comment: english please.

Comment: i changed to english

Comment: I don(t understand, you will not have `note:` anymore within `$text` after `preg_replace`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, we cannot help you because your question is Unclear.  If your incoming data is an object, we are going to need you to isolate the desired string within that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, we don't need a `preg_replace` and `strpos` would be enough:

```
$text = 'some word before then note: and some words after';
$word = "note:";

if (strpos($text, $word) !== false) {
    echo "YAAAY {$word} found in position: " . strpos($text, $word);
}
```

#### Output

```
YAAAY note: found in position: 22
```

Comment: This cannot solve the question.  The question is Unclear.  Please decide how you will adjust your actions due to these facts.